# how to remove comma at the end from the below string in python code

Tags: python, string

input string

```
str = "(\"Cardinal\", \"Tom B. Erichsen\", \"Skagen 21\",)"
```

output string should look like:

```
 ("Cardinal", "Tom B. Erichsen", "Skagen 21")
```

The comma at the end should be removed, help me how to do this in python code.
I tried with str.rstrip(",") it dint work.

Comment: Why are you not using a parametrized query in the first place?

Comment: i want this whole line to be used as a string not a query.

Comment: if you count which character the comma is, you can simply do: str[comma number] = ""

Comment: I may suggest learning regular expressions. They may be hard to use and recognize at the beginning, but can become a very powerful utility.

Comment: @AbdulrahmanAttia that is absolutely not true, strings are immutable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this code

```
str = str.replace('",)', '")')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use some regex for example you can replace `(.*),([^,]+)$` with `\1\2`

```
result = re.sub(r"(.*),([^,]+)$", r"\1\2", yourstring)
```

here is a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/eHGf57/1)

Answer (score 0):

you can chain different `str.replace()`

```
str.replace(", )",")").replace(",)",")")
```

That will work for your string

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in following way

```
str = "(\"Cardinal\", \"Tom B. Erichsen\", \"Skagen 21\",)"

str = str[:len(str)-2] + str[len(str)-1]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the regex module:

```
import re
s = "INSERT INTO Customers (CustomerName, ContactName, Address,  ) VALUES (\"Cardinal\", \"Tom B. Erichsen\", \"Skagen 21\",)"
print re.sub(r',(\s+)*\)', ')', s)
```